# Flickering animation in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, css

I'm doing a slideout login box using only CSS. The problem that I'm facing is that, in FireFox (I'm using Firefox 16.0), the slideout animation flickers. It works fine in chrome and Safari (no animation in IE but doesn't flicker, login box appears fine). 
here is the HTML:

```
<div id="slideout">
        <div id="slideout_inner">
             <form id="loginForm" action="#" method="POST">
                <table cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="lUsername">Username</label></td>
                            <td><label for="lPassword">Password</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="username" id="lUsername" class="required" /></td>
                            <td><input type="password" name="password" id="lPassword" class="required" /></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="error"></span></td>
                            <td><span class="error"></span></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <label>Login</label>
```

and here is the CSS

```
#slideout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
#slideout_inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: -250px;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
#slideout:hover{
  top: 250px;
}
#slideout:hover #slideout_inner{
  top: 0;
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYCtt/) of the problem
How do I fix the flickering in Firefox? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYCtt/2/) may be able to help you.

Write like this:

```
#slideout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#slideout_inner{
    height:0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#slideout:hover #slideout_inner{
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

**OR**

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYCtt/3/).

Comment: I just define the height of **#slideout_inner**. Remove **position:fixed** from it & animated it on hover.